# Optional Still Returning Nil After Assigning Value

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, optional-arguments, swift-optionals

I am working on a similar feature to 'liking/unliking a post'.

I have an MVVM architecture as;

```
struct MyStructModel {
    var isLiked: Bool? = false
}

class MyStructView {
    var isLiked: Bool

    init(myStructModel: MyStructModel) {
        self.isLiked = myStructModel.isLiked ?? false
    }
}
```

I successfully get the value of whether the post is liked or not here;

```
    func isPostLiked(documentID: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    guard let authID = auth.id else { return }
    let query = reference(to: .users).document(authID).collection("liked").document(documentID)
    query.getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
            return
        }
        guard let data = snapshot?.data() else { return }
        if let value = data["isLiked"] as? Bool {
            completion(value)
        } else {
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}

func retrieveReviews(completion: @escaping([MyStructModel]) -> ()) {
    var posts = [MyStructModel]()
    let query = reference(to: .posts).order(by: "createdAt", descending: true)
    query.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error as Any)
            return
        }
        guard let snapshotDocuments = snapshot?.documents else { return }
        for document in snapshotDocuments {
            if var post = try? JSONDecoder().decodeQuery(MyStructModel.self, fromJSONObject: document.decode()) {
                // isLiked is nil here...
                self.isPostLiked(documentID: post.documentID!) { (isLiked) in
                    post.isLiked = isLiked
                    print("MODEL SAYS: \(post.isLiked!)")
                    // isLiked is correct value here...
                }
                posts.append(post)
            }
            completion(posts)
        }
    }
}
```

However, when it gets to my cell the value is still nil.

### Adding Cell Code:

```
var post: MyStructView? {
        didSet {
            guard let post = post else { return }
            print(post.isLiked!)
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post your cell code >?

Comment: Are the tasks async? If so, you should append the post once they are updated.

Comment: I believe so.  If I move the posts.append(post) to within the isPostLiked completion I don't get the posts back.

Comment: The completion handler for retrieveReviews will most likely get called before the completion handler for isPostLiked so isLiked is not set then.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, I believe you are correct. I've printed out the completion for getting posts and its called before the isPostLiked call.  Any ideas how I would solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `isLiked` property is likely nil in your cells because the `retrieveReviews` function doesn't wait for the `isPostLiked` function to complete before completing itself.

You could easily solve this issue by using **DispatchGroups**. This would allow you to make sure all of your Posts have their `isLiked` value properly set before being inserted in the array, and then simply use the DispatchGroup's `notify` block to return all the loaded posts via the completion handler:

```
func retrieveReviews(completion: @escaping([MyStructModel]) -> ()) {
    var posts = [MyStructModel]()
    let query = reference(to: .posts).order(by: "createdAt", descending: true)
    query.getDocuments { [weak self] (snapshot, error) in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        if error != nil {
            return
        }
        guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        for document in documents {
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            if var post = try? JSONDecoder().decodeQuery(MyStructModel.self, fromJSONObject: document.decode()) {
                self.isPostLiked(documentID: post.documentID!) { isLiked in
                    post.isLiked = isLiked
                    posts.append(post)
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }
            }
        }
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            completion(posts)
        }
    }
}
```